# How to obtain Azure subscription details via Ansible module?

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-cli

I am getting started with Ansible + Azure. While I see Ansible modules for quite a few tasks, I am kinda stuck at the basic task of obtaining the subscription_id and subscription_name

To work around this I am using the `az account show --subscription <subscription_name>` command instead. I pull the output of that command into ansible and extract `subscription_id` and `subscription_name`

Is there a way to perform this task via an Ansible module instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks it is not possible to perform this task via the Ansible module, all the Ansible module on Azure [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/list_of_cloud_modules.html#azure), there is no one can do this.

Comment: Unfortunate :( But thanks. I have accepted your answer ( +1 )